# Navigation Menu - Adding Space Between Product Categories & Quantity

Tags: php, wordpress

On a WordPress site, using a custom theme, if you hover over a product category in a drop-down menu, you’ll see something like:

Glucose(8)

See also this screenshot: https://monosnap.com/file/nyPmhxJef67uCi6IlivriCLKlXeZ5o

Whereas, if you look at the cart in the header area, there is a space between the text and the ()... For example: https://monosnap.com/file/s2lPYO6aaGU8Fc7Sc6uCMitabBhBvz

I'm trying to making this consistent (plus having some space there looks better), and it was suggested to me to add a filter on the title, using code such as:

```
function wpforo_add_space_in_menu ( $title ) {
        if( !is_admin() && !in_the_loop() ) {
                $words = explode( '(',  $title );
                $words[0] = $words[0] . ' ';
                $title = implode( '(', $words );
                }
        return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpforo_add_space_in_menu' );
```

I added this to the theme's "funtions.php" file, but I didn't see anything change afterward.

So I'm wondering if there is anything obviously wrong in the code above, or if you can think of another option to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Maybe use `&nbsp;` ???

Comment: If there will be only one `(` then `$title = str_replace('(', '&nbsp;(', $title);`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! If I could find where that function is coded, then I'd be happy to try adding `&nbsp;`

But I tried adding the code from your second comment into the "functions.php" file.  However, that didn't make any change I could see.

BTW,  this appears to be the code in "functions.php":

`function new_submenu_class($menu) {    
    $menu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="sub-menu dropdown-menu" /',$menu);        
    return $menu;      
}`

`add_filter('wp_nav_menu','new_submenu_class');`

Perhaps that will help, but in any case, I appreciate the help.